# Android Studio location permission denied

Tags: java, android

Hello Guys I'm facing "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
Although I included the libraries and also added all the required permissions to Manifest file. when I run the code it is giving me the permission error.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        }

        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.dal.cs.csci3130.quickcash">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".User.SignupActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".User.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.EmployeeDashboardActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.EmployeeHomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.EmployerHomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.ManualSearchActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.PreferencesActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.PreferenceSearchActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.ProfileActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.TaskDescriptionActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home.EmployerCreateJobActivity"></activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You have a commented TODO which you have to complete.

Comment: You're checking permissions at runtime, but not requesting them.  So unless you manually granted them in settings, you don't have them.  Also, you're setting yourself up for hurt by using getLastKnownLocation.  Usually the last location isn't known, so it returns null.  You should instead requestSingleUpdate if you need a location.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 6 you need to request permission at runtime

example:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
```